# Triple-type template container

Tags: c++, template, polymorphism

I made a triple-type container, that is, a single type that can store a value, under one of the three types used. It's somewhat similar to Boost::Variant.

The header file (multitype.hpp):

```
#ifndef MULTITYPE_HPP
#define MULTITYPE_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <typeinfo>

typedef void* vp_t; // Void pointer (can contain every type)

template <typename _A,typename _B> struct is_same_type  { const static bool value = false; };
template <typename _A> struct is_same_type<_A,_A>       { const static bool value = true;  };

template <class A,class B,class C>
class TripleType
{
    protected:
        enum ct_t { _tA, _tB, _tC, _init_ }; // Type flags
        struct abc_t
        {
            A __a;         // A container
            B __b;         // B container
            C __c;         // C container
            ct_t _e; // Which type is the current one?
        };
    private:
        abc_t val;
    public:
        TripleType()
        {
            (this->val)._e = _init_;
        }
        template <class T> TripleType(T x)
        {
            vp_t yv; yv = &x;
            bool is_A = is_same_type<T,A>::value;
            bool is_B = is_same_type<T,B>::value;
            bool is_C = is_same_type<T,C>::value;
            if      (is_A) { A *t = static_cast<A*>(yv); val.__a = *t; val._e = _tA; }
            else if (is_B) { B *t = static_cast<B*>(yv); val.__b = *t; val._e = _tB; }
            else if (is_C) { C *t = static_cast<C*>(yv); val.__c = *t; val._e = _tC; }
        }
        template <class T> TripleType& operator=(T rhs)
        {
            vp_t yv = &rhs;
            bool is_A = is_same_type<T,A>::value;
            bool is_B = is_same_type<T,B>::value;
            bool is_C = is_same_type<T,C>::value;
            if      (is_A) { A *t = static_cast<A*>(yv); (this->val).__a = *t; (this->val)._e = _tA; }
            else if (is_B) { B *t = static_cast<B*>(yv); (this->val).__b = *t; (this->val)._e = _tB; }
            else if (is_C) { C *t = static_cast<C*>(yv); (this->val).__c = *t; (this->val)._e = _tC; }
            return *this;
        }
        template <class T> T get()
        {
            vp_t yv;
            bool is_A = is_same_type<T,A>::value;
            bool is_B = is_same_type<T,B>::value;
            bool is_C = is_same_type<T,C>::value;
            if      (is_A) yv = &(val.__a);
            else if (is_B) yv = &(val.__b);
            else if (is_C) yv = &(val.__c);
            T *t = static_cast<T*>(yv);
            return *t;
        }
        const std::type_info& current_type()
        {
            if      ((this->val)._e == _tA)
                return typeid(A);
            else if ((this->val)._e == _tB)
                return typeid(B);
            else if ((this->val)._e == _tC)
                return typeid(C);
        }
};

#endif
```

Here is an usage example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include "multitype.hpp" // The header file where I wrote the mentioned container

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    TripleType<int,string,float> test;
    test = rand();
    cout << test.get<int>() << endl;
    test = string("TripleType test");
    cout << test.get<string>() << endl;
    test = float(1.6108);
    cout << test.get<float>() << endl;
    test = 2016;
    cout << test.get<int>() << endl;
    test = string("Bye.");
    cout << test.get<string>() << endl;
}
```

Any improvements, suggestions, etc. are welcome.

Comment: When you are making a variant type, it is better to use a `union` than a `struct`. That's how you get the space savings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't make it possible for your container to contain nothing. It can be wrapped in a `std::optional` for that. Drop the `_init_` type and parameterless constructor.
2. Use `val` consistently. The parentheses around `this->val` are unnecessary anyway, but since you're already using `val` in some places, just use it everywhere.
3. Don't allow construction or assignment with values of bad types. That fails silently right now, which is not a good way to fail. Luckily, you can do even better and keep the static typing with overloading:

   ```
   TripleType(A x) { val._e = _tA; val.__a = x; }
   TripleType(B x) { val._e = _tB; val.__b = x; }
   TripleType(C x) { val._e = _tC; val.__c = x; }

   TripleType& operator=(A x) { val._e = _tA; val.__a = x; return *this; }
   TripleType& operator=(B x) { val._e = _tB; val.__b = x; return *this; }
   TripleType& operator=(C x) { val._e = _tC; val.__c = x; return *this; }
   ```
4. Mark methods that don't modify their object – `get()` and `current_type()` – as `const`.
5. Don't allow fetching values of the wrong type. I'm not a C++ expert by any means, so there might be a better way of restricting `T` to `A`, `B`, or `C` while keeping the same `.get<T>` calling convention (I sure hope so), but:

   ```
   private:
       A get_(A const*) const {
           if (val._e != _tA) {
               throw bad_multitype_access(typeid(A), current_type());
           }

           return val.__a;
       }

       B get_(B const*) const {
           if (val._e != _tB) {
               throw bad_multitype_access(typeid(B), current_type());
           }

           return val.__b;
       }

       C get_(C const*) const {
           if (val._e != _tC) {
               throw bad_multitype_access(typeid(C), current_type());
           }

           return val.__c;
       }

   public:
       template <class T> T get() const {
           return get_(static_cast<T const*>(nullptr));
       }
   ```

   where `bad_multitype_access` would be something along the lines of:

   ```
   class bad_multitype_access : std::logic_error {
   public:
       bad_multitype_access(std::type_info const& expected, std::type_info const& actual) :
           std::logic_error(std::string("Attempted to get ") + expected.name() + " from multitype containing " + actual.name()) {}
   };
   ```

   That's all verbose and a bit hacky, but prevents getting types outside of the expected set statically and values of the wrong type dynamically. Again, I would love to hear a better way of accomplishing the same thing from someone who actually knows the language. You can also drop the `vp_t` typedef at this point, which was never really a good idea, as well as `is_same_type`.
6. Use a `switch` for `current_type()`.

   ```
   std::type_info const& current_type() const {
       switch (val._e) {
       case _tA: return typeid(A);
       case _tB: return typeid(B);
       case _tC: return typeid(C);
       }
   }
   ```
7. Stop it with the underscores already! =)

   ```
   private:
       enum contained_type {
           tA,
           tB,
           tC,
       };

       struct {
           A a;
           B b;
           C c;
           contained_type type;
       } val;
   ```
8. It feels like creating a `TripleType` shouldn't create an instance of each of its possible types, and that writing a new value of a different type should destroy a previously existing one. `unique_ptr`s could work here.

   ```
   private:
       ⋮
       struct {
           std::unique_ptr<A> a;
           std::unique_ptr<B> b;
           std::unique_ptr<C> c;
           contained_type type;
       } val;
       ⋮
           return *val.a;
       ⋮
           return *val.b;
       ⋮
           return *val.c;

   public:
       TripleType(A x) { val.type = tA; val.a = std::make_unique<A>(x); }
       TripleType(B x) { val.type = tB; val.b = std::make_unique<B>(x); }
       TripleType(C x) { val.type = tC; val.c = std::make_unique<C>(x); }

       TripleType& operator=(A x) {
           val.type = tA;
           val.a = std::make_unique<A>(x);
           val.b.reset(nullptr);
           val.c.reset(nullptr);
           return *this;
       }

       TripleType& operator=(B x) {
           val.type = tB;
           val.a.reset(nullptr);
           val.b = std::make_unique<B>(x);
           val.c.reset(nullptr);
           return *this;
       }

       TripleType& operator=(C x) {
           val.type = tC;
           val.a.reset(nullptr);
           val.b.reset(nullptr);
           val.c = std::make_unique<C>(x);
           return *this;
       }
   ```
9. Avoid the double-copy-construct by accepting `T const&` instead of `T` in the constructors and `operator=`s.
10. Since `TripleType` is managing everything about `val`, move `val`'s members into it; it's just doing namespacing right now and not representing an actual object.
11. Give `TripleType` some copy and move constructors.

    ```
    TripleType(TripleType<A, B, C> const& o) {
        type = o.type;

        switch (type) {
        case tA: a = std::make_unique<A>(*o.a); break;
        case tB: b = std::make_unique<B>(*o.b); break;
        case tC: c = std::make_unique<C>(*o.c); break;
        }
    }

    TripleType(TripleType<A, B, C>&& o) = default;
    ```

All told, it looks like this now:

```
#ifndef MULTITYPE_HPP
#define MULTITYPE_HPP

#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>

class bad_multitype_access : std::logic_error {
public:
    bad_multitype_access(std::type_info const& expected, std::type_info const& actual) :
        std::logic_error(std::string("Attempted to get ") + expected.name() + " from multitype containing " + actual.name()) {}
};

template <class A, class B, class C>
class TripleType {
private:
    enum contained_type {
        tA,
        tB,
        tC,
    };

    std::unique_ptr<A> a;
    std::unique_ptr<B> b;
    std::unique_ptr<C> c;
    contained_type type;

    A get_(A const*) const {
        if (type != tA) {
            throw bad_multitype_access(typeid(A), current_type());
        }

        return *a;
    }

    B get_(B const*) const {
        if (type != tB) {
            throw bad_multitype_access(typeid(B), current_type());
        }

        return *b;
    }

    C get_(C const*) const {
        if (type != tC) {
            throw bad_multitype_access(typeid(C), current_type());
        }

        return *c;
    }

public:
    TripleType(TripleType<A, B, C> const& o) {
        type = o.type;

        switch (type) {
        case tA: a = std::make_unique<A>(*o.a); break;
        case tB: b = std::make_unique<B>(*o.b); break;
        case tC: c = std::make_unique<C>(*o.c); break;
        }
    }

    TripleType(TripleType<A, B, C>&& o) = default;

    TripleType(A const& x) { type = tA; a = std::make_unique<A>(x); }
    TripleType(B const& x) { type = tB; b = std::make_unique<B>(x); }
    TripleType(C const& x) { type = tC; c = std::make_unique<C>(x); }

    TripleType& operator=(A const& x) {
        type = tA;
        a = std::make_unique<A>(x);
        b.reset(nullptr);
        c.reset(nullptr);
        return *this;
    }

    TripleType& operator=(B const& x) {
        type = tB;
        a.reset(nullptr);
        b = std::make_unique<B>(x);
        c.reset(nullptr);
        return *this;
    }

    TripleType& operator=(C const& x) {
        type = tC;
        a.reset(nullptr);
        b.reset(nullptr);
        c = std::make_unique<C>(x);
        return *this;
    }

    template <class T> T get() const {
        return get_(static_cast<T const*>(nullptr));
    }

    std::type_info const& current_type() const noexcept {
        switch (type) {
        case tA: return typeid(A);
        case tB: return typeid(B);
        case tC: return typeid(C);
        }
    }
};
#endif
```

And now there's more type safety. (I hope this isn't actually egregiously bad advice!)

Also, here are some moving constructors and `operator=`s you can add.

```
TripleType(A&& x) { type = tA; a = std::make_unique<A>(std::move(x)); }
TripleType(B&& x) { type = tB; b = std::make_unique<B>(std::move(x)); }
TripleType(C&& x) { type = tC; c = std::make_unique<C>(std::move(x)); }

TripleType& operator=(A&& x) {
    type = tA;
    a = std::make_unique<A>(std::move(x));
    b.reset(nullptr);
    c.reset(nullptr);
    return *this;
}

TripleType& operator=(B&& x) {
    type = tB;
    a.reset(nullptr);
    b = std::make_unique<B>(std::move(x));
    c.reset(nullptr);
    return *this;
}

TripleType& operator=(C&& x) {
    type = tC;
    a.reset(nullptr);
    b.reset(nullptr);
    c = std::make_unique<C>(std::move(x));
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: ad 9, if you use `std::move()` then passing the arguments by value is not that bad idea at all.

Comment: Wow, this is great! Also, I've never thought about using `switch`es. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### Unions

You should use a [*tagged union*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) instead of storing all three types. That's how `boost::variant` works and that's the best approach since the container is storing only one of the three types at any time.

Starting with C++11, we can declare unrestricted unions, that is, it doesn't matter if the object is Plain old Data (POD) or has a constructor/destructor.

```
enum class Type { TA, TB, TC };
union Data
{
    A asA;
    B asB;
    C asC;
};

Data data; // The raw data
Type type; // The "tag"
```

The union `Data` will only use enough space to store the largest of the three values, so if you have `<int, std::string, float>`, `sizeof(Data) == sizeof(std::string)`. (assuming string is the largest of the three).

With a union, you're responsible for constructing and destroying the stored value though, so for instance, when assigning or initializing we have to invoke the constructor with [placement new](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new):

```
template <class T> TripleType& operator = (const T& rhs)
{
    // Note should first destroy the current value if necessary
    // E.g.: data.asA.~T();

    switch (type)
    {
    case Type::TA :
        ::new(&data.asA) T(rhs);
        type = Type::TA;
        break;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Similarly, in `~TripleType()` you will have to switch on the type tag again and call the appropriate destructor.

Since not all types require calling a constructor and a destructor, you could take advantage of tools like [`std::is_pod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pod) and use some template tricks to avoid calling constructor/destructor where it is not needed, but that will add some complexity to the code, so consider this as an optimization that might take some work.

---

#### Other bits:

- Names with double underscore are reserved for use in the Standard Library internals and for compiler extensions. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/1198654).
- You should pay more mind to naming in a few places. `yv` or `_e` are pretty unclear. Your code was not very complex this time, so they didn't completely impede understanding, but don't be lazy, think of good names always!
- It is not very usual to `this->` qualify member variables in C++ classes. The usual scenario for that is when someone is trying to disambiguate a shadowed/conflicting name, which is just a way of hiding a much worse problem. If you'd like to differentiate the member variables from local ones, consider using a prefix like `m_` (`m_something`) or a suffix `_` (`something_`).
- No need to expose `<iostream>` in your header file. Keep your headers clean by only importing what is needed.
- This was already mentioned and it is worth repeating: Make thorough use of `const` whenever it makes sense. Declare methods that won't change member data as `const`. See [What is a "const member function"?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-member-fns).